# Repetir un print determinadas veces en un while

Tags: python

```
numero1 = 1

print("Desde el")

while True:

    print("Número {}".format( numero1 ))
    numero1 = numero1 + 1

    print("hasta el")

    if numero1 == 11:
        break
```

el resultado es:

```
Desde el
Número 1
hasta el
Número 2
hasta el
Número 3
hasta el
Número 4
hasta el
Número 5
hasta el
Número 6
hasta el
Número 7
hasta el
Número 8
hasta el
Número 9
hasta el
Número 10
hasta el
```

y quisiera que fuera:

```
Desde el número 1
2 
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
hasta el número 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que desea es solo imprimir el valor de la variable `numero1`  , no veo necesario utilizar `format` simplemente imprimir la variable

```
numero1 = 1
#Imprimimos el número
print "Desde el numero " , numero1
#Incrementamos para iniciar en 2
numero1 = numero1 + 1

while True:
    # si es igual a 10 matamos el ciclo
    if numero1 == 10:
      print "hasta el numero ", numero1
      break

    #caso contrario imprimimos el número e 
    #incrementamos la variable
    print numero1 
    numero1 = numero1 + 1
```

Aunque para mejorar un poco la lectura y no cambiar mucho y funcione con un inicio o final cualquiera,podría haber declarado 2 variables , `inicio` y `final` e iterar a través de un `for` , con `range(inicio,final):` es decir comenzará con el valor de inicio y terminará cuando llegue al valor de final , esto es parecido al típico `i < n` de los `for` clásicos, para este caso sería `inicio < final`

```
inicio = 1
final = 10
#Imprimimos el número
print "Desde el numero " , inicio
#Incrementamos para iniciar en 2
inicio+=1
for x in range(inicio,final):
  print x

print "Hasta el numero " , final
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra que le haya servido. Recuerde leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para saber el funcionamiento de cuando un usuario responde una pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción muy simple para la salida que quieres usando un `while` es prescindir del condicional y el `break`  y usar la variable `numero1` como variable de control del ciclo directamente (con esto se evita comprobar dos condiciones en cada iteración):

```
numero1 = 1

print("Desde el número", numero1)

while numero1 < 10:
    numero1 += 1
    print(numero1)

print("hasta el número", numero1)
```

En Python 3, donde `print` es una función, puedes usar un generador con un `for` directamente en el `print`:

```
inicio = 1
final = 10

print("Desde el número", inicio)
print(*(n for n in range(inicio+1, final)), sep='\n')
print("hasta el número", final)
```